# Migrate from require to import es6 with yargs

Tags: node.js, yargs

I am doing some code samples with node.js and yargs and I am trying to access yargs.command and yargs.version which I easily had access to with require.

But when I use import with the line:

`import * as yargs from 'yargs';`

It returns an error saying * is an invalid token

How can I successfully migrate to import?

Answer (score 5):

This is just to elaborate @[Moreorem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6629864/moreorem)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61157872/4675524) (because I spent my sometime to properly figure it out :P)-

File - `script.js`

```js
import Yargs from "yargs";
const args = Yargs(process.argv.slice(2)).argv;
console.log(args.arg1);
```

Command -

```sh
node script.js --arg1=xyz
```

Output -

```sh
xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `import argv from 'yargs';`

then you can use the arguments likewise
`node app.js --name Mike --port 22144`

e.g. console.log(argv.name, argv.port) ...